# Android how to update progress bar in the listview, while uploading file to Amazon using aws sdk

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, android-listview, amazon-s3, android-progressbar

Am using the aws SDK to upload set of images. I have a ListView with each list item containing a ProgressBar(Style:Horizontal), I need to set the progress to it based on the file uploaded.

I used the TransferManager from the aws SDK (http://aws.amazon.com/releasenotes/Java/3538638977238478) to get the uploaded data.

I tried this, But its not working:

```
public class SyncFragment extends Fragment {

    ListView uploadList;
    public UploadAdapter uploadAdapter;

    public ArrayList<QueueItem> queueList = new ArrayList<QueueItem>();

    AWSCredentials myCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(Constants.ACCESS_KEY_ID, Constants.SECRET_KEY);
    TransferManager tm = new TransferManager(myCredentials);

    // Empty cons as per documentation of Fragments
    public SyncFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        // Set the queue list
        queueList = ((NSApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).queueList;
        // Init Adapter
        uploadAdapter = new UploadAdapter(getActivity());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.upload_list, container, false);

        uploadList = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.uploadList);
        uploadList.setAdapter(uploadAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    class UploadAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QueueItem> {

        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        private BitmapFromId bitmapFromId;
        QueueItem item;

        public UploadAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, 0);
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            bitmapFromId = new BitmapFromId(context);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Set the total list item count
            return queueList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public QueueItem getItem(int position) {
            return queueList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_upload, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.albumName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.albumTitle);
                holder.thumb = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumb);
                holder.progressBar = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar_Horizontal);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            item = getItem(position);

            item.progress = 0;

            // load bitmap from id
            bitmapFromId.DisplayImage(Long.parseLong(item.itemId), holder.thumb);

            holder.albumName.setText(item.itemName);

            S3PutObjectTask task = new S3PutObjectTask();
            task.execute(item.itemActualPath, item.itemId);

            holder.progressBar.setProgress(item.progress);

            return convertView;
        }

        private class S3PutObjectTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, S3TaskResult> {

            int progress;

            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progress = 0;
            }

            protected S3TaskResult doInBackground(String... params) {

                S3TaskResult result = new S3TaskResult();
                // The file location of the image selected.
                String imagePath = params[0];

                // Put the image data into S3.
                try {

                    File image = new java.io.File(imagePath);

                    Transfer myUpload = tm.upload(Constants.getPictureBucket(), params[1] + ".jpg", image);

                    while (myUpload.isDone() == false) {
                        progress = (int) (myUpload.getProgress().getBytesTransfered() * 100 / image.length());
                        publishProgress(progress);
                    }

                    myUpload.waitForCompletion();

                } catch (Exception exception) {

                    result.setErrorMessage(exception.getMessage());
                }

                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                item.progress = values[0];
                uploadAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(S3TaskResult result) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "uploaded sucessfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (result.getErrorMessage() != null) {

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "upload failed...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }

        public class S3TaskResult {
            String errorMessage = null;
            Uri uri = null;

            public String getErrorMessage() {
                return errorMessage;
            }

            public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
                this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
            }

            public Uri getUri() {
                return uri;
            }

            public void setUri(Uri uri) {
                this.uri = uri;
            }
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView thumb;
        TextView albumName;
        ProgressBar progressBar;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what's not working?  Is the upload completing but you're just not getting progress?  Have you tried using the ProgressListener interface? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSAndroidSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ProgressListener.html

Comment: @BobKinney Hi bob thanks for the comment, I tried even with the 'ProgressListner' but it does not give the progress or the number of bytes transfered.. Any ways the Transfer should also return me the bytes transfered right.

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear, the upload is completing but you're just not getting correct progress updates?

Comment: @BobKinney Yes! the uploading is completed and onPostExecute am settings the progress to 100 this works, (One done the progress from 0 to it jumps to 100) but am not able to set the progress timely.. :(

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I see from your code:

- The way you use TransferManager and the idea to update transfer progress are correct. However I suggest you update the progress once more outside the while loop to get the finish state right.
- "QueueItem item" in UploadAdapter is very suspicious. All your S3PutObjectTask objects share one item whose value is assigned in getView and is overwritten when Android draws every list item. I believe the progress will mess up when there are more than one tasks running. It's better to associate a queue item and a task together, so that the task can update its progress via associated queue item.
- Due to view recycling in Android, tasks can be restarted when a list item is redrawn.

I hope the above helps you diagnose the problem.